# Let's play a game of Truth or Dare

Tags: riddle, rhyme, poetry

Let's play a game of Truth or Dare.
I am the latter, if you're unaware.
Although I'm sweet, I'll sour your mind.
There could be some truth in the lie you find.

What am I?

Hint:

> I am a lie to begin with, but I might become true.

Hint 2:

> A qualified professional is taking a gamble.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you:

> A placebo

Let's play a game of Truth or Dare.
I am the latter, if you're unaware.

> Doctors prescribe placebos to unknowing patients (unaware) at the doctor's risk (dare) as opposed to real medication (truth).  This can alternately be done in a medical trial in which case the patient would be the one taking the risk or dare as they're gambling on whether or not they will be receiving treatment for their condition.

Although I'm sweet, I'll sour your mind.

> Placebos are commonly "sugar pills".  The pill is tricking the patient (souring their mind).

There could be some truth in the lie you find.

> The patient could get better from taking the placebo, due to the placebo effect, in which case the fake medication would've had real efficacy due to belief.

Answer (score 6):

Could it be

> A dream

I am the latter, if you're unaware.

> If you're not conscious ("unaware"), you're dreaming, so it's not the Truth. Also, "Dare to dream" is a saying

Although I'm sweet, I'll sour your mind.

> They say "sweet dreams", but (I have just learned) "Sour Dream" is a variety of marijuana, which will IMHO surely "sour your mind"

There could be some truth in the lie you find.

> They say "dreams can come true", which also aligns with the hint

Comment: Nice answer but it's not the right one.

Answer (score 2):

A flimsy attempt

> drugs

Let's play a game of Truth or Dare.

I am the latter, if you're unaware.

> D.A.R.E. is a drug abuse resistance education program

Although I'm sweet, I'll sour your mind.

There could be some truth in the lie you find.

> Drugs feel sweet, but they damage your brain - sour your mind

Comment: It's not the correct answer, but by random luck you're actually not that far off.